# Export SVG tag as image from HTML webpage

Tags: html, image, svg

I am trying to export an image from an `<svg>` tag in an html page.

I have copied the whole svg tag and pasted in notepad saved in .svg extension.

But I get this error: This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

I have tried to use svg crowbar 2 in Chrome but this isn't working for me.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: you're missing xmlns attributes. They are not necessary in HTML but are mandatory in XML.

Comment: Super thanks it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the svg tag insert this: **xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"**

Like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="example-1" viewBox="0 0 12 12">
```